# How to open an activity and a particular destination using Android navigation component and deeplink

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-deep-link

I want to open a new activity and in that I want to navigate to a particular destination using deeplinks.
I have read about NavDeepLinkBuilder, however they are using with Pending intents.

What I want to do is this:

```
val url = getString(R.string.deeplink_account_overview)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
        startActivity(intent)
```

Is there anyway to do the exact same thing using navigation component?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation jetpack already support deep link.
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit
After setup steps:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply { data = "url".toUri() }
startActivity(intent)
```